# Grails transaction never completes

Tags: mysql, grails, transactions, grails-orm, grails-2.0

Consider the code below, that tries to create a new `SerpKeyword` within a transaction and prints to the console to show where it is.

```
    if (!serpKeyword) {
        println "I DIDN'T FIND THE KEYWORD!"
        SerpKeyword.withNewTransaction {
            println "SO NOW I'M BEGINNING A TRANSACTION"
            serpKeyword = new SerpKeyword(
                    keyword: searchKeyword,
                    geoKeyword: geoKeyword,
                    concatenation: concatenation,
                    locale: locale
            )
            println "NOW I'LL SAVE THE KEYWORD"
            serpKeyword.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
            println "AND NOW THE KEYWORD IS SAVED"
        }
    }
```

The console output I see right away is:

```
I DIDN'T FIND THE KEYWORD!
SO NOW I'M BEGINNING A TRANSACTION
NOW I'LL SAVE THE KEYWORD
```

I never see the last line of my output, indicating that the record never saves. I've tried this both with and without the options that I'm passing into `save`. Regardless, it just hangs for a while, and eventually I get this stacktrace:

```
Got error -1 from storage engine. Stacktrace follows:
java.sql.SQLException: Got error -1 from storage engine
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2019)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1937)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1922)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at com.reachlocal.grails.sales.AdvertiserConnectionService$_findOrCreateSerpKeyword_closure9$$EO2A9QHA.doCall(AdvertiserConnectionService.groovy:624)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withNewTransaction(GormStaticApi.groovy:696)
    at com.reachlocal.grails.sales.AdvertiserConnectionService$$EO2A9QHA.findOrCreateSerpKeyword(AdvertiserConnectionService.groovy:615)
    at com.reachlocal.grails.sales.AdvertiserConnectionService$$EO2A9QHA.createSerpEntryForKeyword(AdvertiserConnectionService.groovy:659)
    at com.reachlocal.grails.sales.AdvertiserConnectionService$$EO2A9QHA.addKeyword(AdvertiserConnectionService.groovy:51)
    at com.reachlocal.grails.serp.SerpController$_closure9.doCall(SerpController.groovy:77)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:65)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

What gives?

Comment: Maybe your table is corrupted. Can you perform a direct insert?

Answer (score 1):

You may get the "Got error -1 from storage engine" for several reasons:

1. Your database is out of disk space
2. You have the `innodb_force_recovery` switch in your my.cnf file
3. Mismatched MySQL tablespace ids.

The best way to troubleshoot this issue is to take a look at the [MySQL error log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-log.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the id generation strategy set as `assigned` any thing other than a `sequence/auto` in the domain class `serpKeyword`?

It will be helpful to debug if you can add the domain class in the post as well.